# Iteratively parsing HTML (with lxml?)

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml, iterparse

I'm currently trying to iteratively parse a very large HTML document (I know.. yuck) using [`lxml.etree.iterparse`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.iterparse-class.html):

> Incremental parser.
> Parses XML into a tree and generates tuples (event, element) in a
> SAX-like fashion

I am using an incremental/iterative/SAX approach to [reduce the amount of memory used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6828897/1175496) (I don't want to load the HTML into a DOM/tree because the file is large)

The problem I'm having is that I'm getting XML syntax errors such as:

`lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Attribute name redefined, line 134, column 59`

This then causes everything to stop.

Is there a way to iteratively parse HTML without choking on syntax errors?

At the moment I'm extracting the line number from the XML syntax error exception, removing that line from the document, and then restarting the process. Seems like a pretty disgusting solution. Is there a better way?

**Edit:**

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
context = etree.iterparse(tfile, events=('start', 'end'), html=True)
in_table = False
header_row = True
while context:
    try:
        event, el = context.next()
        
        # do something

        # remove old elements
        while el.getprevious() is not None:
            del el.getparent()[0]

    except etree.XMLSyntaxError, e:
        print e.msg
        lineno = int(re.search(r'line (\d+),', e.msg).group(1))
        remove_line(tfilename, lineno)
        tfile = open(tfilename)
        context = etree.iterparse(tfile, events=('start', 'end'), html=True)
    except KeyError:
        print 'oops keyerror'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The perfect solution ended up being Python's very own [`HTMLParser` <sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html).

This is the (pretty bad) code I ended up using:

```
class MyParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.finished = False
        self.in_table = False
        self.in_row = False
        self.in_cell = False
        self.current_row = []
        self.current_cell = ''
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        attrs = dict(attrs)
        if not self.in_table:
            if tag == 'table':
                if ('id' in attrs) and (attrs['id'] == 'dgResult'):
                    self.in_table = True
        else:
            if tag == 'tr':
                self.in_row = True
            elif tag == 'td':
                self.in_cell = True
            elif (tag == 'a') and (len(self.current_row) == 7):
                url = attrs['href']
                self.current_cell = url


    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == 'tr':
            if self.in_table:
                if self.in_row:
                    self.in_row = False
                    print self.current_row
                    self.current_row = []
        elif tag == 'td':
            if self.in_table:
                if self.in_cell:
                    self.in_cell = False
                    self.current_row.append(self.current_cell.strip())
                    self.current_cell = ''

        elif (tag == 'table') and self.in_table:
            self.finished = True

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if not len(self.current_row) == 7:
            if self.in_cell:
                self.current_cell += data
```

With that code I could then do this:

```
parser = MyParser()
for line in myfile:
    parser.feed(line)
```

Answer (score 6):

At the moment lxml etree.iterparse [supports keyword argument recover=True](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/d3a671fa61cb1ad1291440e554b9caad184dcc74/src/lxml/iterparse.pxi#L36), so that instead of writing custom subclass of HTMLParser fixing broken html you can just pass this argument to iterparse.

To properly parse huge and broken html you only need to do following:

```
etree.iterparse(tfile, events=('start', 'end'), html=True, recover=True)
```

Comment: This is the best answer for me.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. But please note if `html` is true and `recover` is not specified then `recover` [will be True](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/d3a671fa61cb1ad1291440e554b9caad184dcc74/src/lxml/iterparse.pxi#L83) as mentioned in the documentation "recover: try hard to parse through broken input (**default: True for HTML**)" for `iterparse` http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.iterparse-class.html

Comment: Oh so the `lxml` version **2.3** available around the time of OP's question (December, 2011), [doesn't have the `recover` argument"](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/lxml-2.3/src/lxml/iterparse.pxi#L321). Looks like `recover` argument was introduced in `lxml` [version **3.3**](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/lxml-3.3/src/lxml/iterparse.pxi#L5) (released in [January 2014](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/3.3.0/)) , so it's good @Pawel point out the `recover` argument! (But OP doesn't need to change their code (they use `html=True`), just update `lxml`!)

Answer (score 1):

Use `True` for [iterparse](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.iterparse-class.html)'s arguments `html` and `huge_tree`.

Comment: I am currently using `html=True`, it still raises XML syntax errors. I'll take a look at the `huge_tree` parameter.

Comment: `huge_tree` doesn't seem relevant: "huge_tree: disable security restrictions and support very deep trees". My tree isn't deep, just long.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for rehashing an old question, but for late comers who are searching for solutions, `lxml` version 3.3 has [`HTMLPullParser` and `XMLPullParser`](https://lxml.de/3.3/changes-3.3.0.html#beta1-2013-12-12) which parse incrementally. One can also check out [`lxml` introduction to parsing](https://lxml.de/parsing.html) for more examples.

If you want to parse a very large document and save memory, you can [write a custom target class](https://lxml.de/parsing.html#events-with-custom-targets) as event handler to avoid building the element tree. Something like:

```py
class MyParserTarget:
    def start(self, tag, attrib) -> None:
        # do something
    def end(self, tag) -> None:
        # do something
    def data(self, data) -> None:
        # do something
    def close(self):
        # return your result

mytarget = MyParserTarget()
parser = lxml.etree.HTMLPullParser(target=mytarget)
parser.feed(next(content))
# Do other stuff
result = parser.close()
```

If you continue to use `etree.iterparse(..., html=True)` as in the OP question, [it will use `HtmlPullParser` under the hood](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/lxml-3.3/src/lxml/iterparse.pxi#L90)., but `iterparse` will **not pass a [custom target instance](https://lxml.de/parsing.html#events-with-custom-targets)** (like I show here), not even in the [latest version of `lxml`](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/lxml-4.6/src/lxml/iterparse.pxi).  Therefore if you prefer a custom target approach (vs `events` argument as shown in OP), you can use `HtmlPullParser` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing your HTML document with [lxml.html](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html):

> Since version 2.0, lxml comes with a dedicated Python package for dealing with HTML: lxml.html. It is based on lxml's HTML parser, but provides a special Element API for HTML elements, as well as a number of utilities for common HTML processing tasks.

Comment: I'm trying to iteratively parse the document due to its large size. lxml.html does not have an iterparse function as far as I can tell.

Comment: I suggested lxml.html because in the OP there was no mention of trying lxml.html.  I think that down-voting my answer is rather misguided.