# lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';'

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to figure out the python lxml api, but am running into a peculiar problem.  I've installed the following library versions:

- libxml2 : 2.7.8
- libxslt : 1.1.26

When I run the following code:

```
html = open('file.html', 'r')
context = etree.iterparse(StringIO(html), events=("start", "end"), html='true')
for event, element in context:
    #do stuff
```

### EDIT :

It turns out that it is a parsing error.  I moved the html to a file(shown below)

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>image</td>
                <a href="relative.phtml?with=querystring&blah=blah">blah\n(blah)</a></td>
                <td>   35   </td>
                <td>   28   </td>
                <td><b>-7</b></td>
                <td>   
                23,000    </td>
                <td>   373,000   </td>
                <td>   644,000   </td>
                <td>+72.65%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>image</td>
                <td><a href="relative.phtml?with=querystring&blah=blah">blah\n(blah)</a></td>
                <td>   35   </td>
                <td>   28   </td>
                <td><b>-7</b></td>
                <td>   
                23,000    </td>
                <td>   373,000   </td>
                <td>   644,000   </td>
                <td>+72.65%</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm now getting this error:

> for event, element in context:
>
> File "iterparse.pxi", line 515, in lxml.etree.iterparse.**next**
>   (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:86484)   File "parser.pxi", line 565, in
>   lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:64084)
>   lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: error parsing attribute name, line 1,
>   column 12

ORIGIN ERROR:

> for event, element in context:
>
> File "iterparse.pxi", line 515, in lxml.etree.iterparse.**next**
>   (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:86484)   File "parser.pxi", line 565, in
>   lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:64084)
>   lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';', line 7,
>   column 71

I thought I followed the tutorial from lxml's [site](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#event-driven-parsing) pretty closely here so I'm very confused.  Could it be an installation problem?

Comment: Is that the actual HTML you're parsing? What happens if you build the same HTML with the E builder?

Comment: that's not the actual html, I replaced it with '...' for brevity

Comment: It looks be failing on a real parse error. If you have trivial HTML, does it succeed?

Comment: you were right.  Trivial HTML does go through.  I've updated the question accordingly.  This doesn't even strike me as poorly constructed HTML though?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the HTML is malformed. To solve this, you can use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (it's able to parse this HTML) or sanitize the HTML before trying to parse it.

The problems I've found are:

- Ampersand should be escaped as an HTML entity in links: `&` => `&amp;`
- Closing `td` tag after first `a` tag has to be removed since it doesn't match any other opening `td` tag.

Comment: Thanks.  I was using BeautifulSoup and then I switched over to lxml because I read that it can deal with large files better since it supports iterative parsing.  I now there's a BeautifulSoup interface with lxml so maybe I'll try looking there

Answer (score 4):

lxml `iterparse` can't parse broken html. If you have a really big file, or memory limitations, you can write your own parser like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8484265/1052325). But if you are allowed to store whole tree into memory, you can use `lxml.html`, which is faster than `BeautifulSoup`.