# org.w3c.dom.ls.LSException Caused by: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: java, dom

I have to save a XML file. I'm using DOm and the file is huge, about 1,3 Gb. For doing this i use the next code:

```
public void guardarDocumentoXML() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    DOMImplementationLS ls = (DOMImplementationLS)documentoXML.getImplementation();
    LSSerializer ser = ls.createLSSerializer();
    LSOutput out = ls.createLSOutput();
    out.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(nombrearchivo);
    try {
        out.setByteStream(output);
        ser.write(documentoXML, out);
    } finally {
        output.close();
    }
}
```

When I try to save small XML file i have no problem, but when I try to save a huge file i receive the next exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" org.w3c.dom.ls.LSException
at org.apache.xml.serializer.dom3.LSSerializerImpl.write(LSSerializerImpl.java:1087)
at datos.XML_Seguridad.guardarDocumentoXML(XML_Seguridad.java:824)
at datos.GUI$1ButtonListener.actionPerformed(GUI.java:2100)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
at org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializerBase.characters(SerializerBase.java:958)
at org.apache.xml.serializer.dom3.DOM3TreeWalker.dispatachChars(DOM3TreeWalker.java:381)
at org.apache.xml.serializer.dom3.DOM3TreeWalker.serializeText(DOM3TreeWalker.java:1040)
at org.apache.xml.serializer.dom3.DOM3TreeWalker.startNode(DOM3TreeWalker.java:429)
at org.apache.xml.serializer.dom3.DOM3TreeWalker.traverse(DOM3TreeWalker.java:272)
at org.apache.xml.serializer.dom3.DOM3SerializerImpl.serializeDOM3(DOM3SerializerImpl.java:111)
at org.apache.xml.serializer.dom3.LSSerializerImpl.write(LSSerializerImpl.java:1069)
... 37 more
```

I use Xerces 2.11 library.
Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: sounds like a bug in xerces. Contact them on their mailing list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Xerces2 Java 2.11.0` depends on `serializer.jar`. In this library you will find the `org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializerBase` class.

The code [`m_charsBuff = new char\[length * 2 + 1\];`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.xalan/com.springsource.org.apache.xml.serializer/2.7.1/org/apache/xml/serializer/SerializerBase.java?av=f#947) (on line 958) indicates that even if length were somehow negative (due to a bug) then the array would always be created with a positive number. The fact a [`NegativeArraySizeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NegativeArraySizeException.html) is being raised which is

> Thrown if an application tries to create an array with negative size.

suggests an [**integer overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo) caused by the `length * 2 + 1` calculation. I believe this is occurring because the XML document supplied to the DOM parser is **very** large.

I'd consider using a SAX parser instead - see [What is the difference between SAX and DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828703/difference-about-sax-and-dom) for a comparison.