# Read Inner XML of a XML Element

Tags: java, xml

I was looking thru StackOverflow but i can't find best answer. I need to read XML file in JAVA. My XML file looks like below: `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<server>
    <server01>
       <department>A1</department>
       <department>A2</department> 
    </server01>
    <server02>
       <department>A1</department>
       <department>A2</department> 
    </server02>
</server>
```

Is there a possiblity to read in Java elements between `<server01>` and `<server02>`, excluding rest of file? Or I need to use different tags? I found method how to read parentnodes:

```
NodeList serversNames = xmlD.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();

for (int i = 0; i < serversNames.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = serversNames.item(i);
    if (node instanceof Element) {
        Element childElement = (Element) node;
        System.out.println("tag name: " + childElement.getTagName());
    }
}
```

I am able to read all departments tags and save them to array:

```
NodeList serverName = xmlD.getElementsByTagName("department");

serversList = new String[serverName.getLength()];

System.out.println("zasieg: " + serverName.getLength());

for (int temp = 0; temp < serverName.getLength(); temp++) {
    Element shareName = null;

    shareName = (Element) serverName.item(temp);

    serversList[temp] = shareName.getTextContent();
    System.out.println(temp + " - " + serversList[temp]);
}
```

So, again, is there a possibility to read elements of parent node only? Elements of SERVER01 only?

Comment: Are you saying you want to stop reading the document after you have read the contents of <server01> and so not read in the contents of <server02>? I think you need to define that logic in your program, it won't really be part of any XML parser.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do or what the issue is. Can't you just use XPath or the equivalent? If you use an event-driven parser you can stop whenever you want, if it's really worth it.

Comment: you can use xstream to convert to XML to object and object to XML, Its very easy way to convert XML to object and object to XML.

Comment: Here is a useful reference: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/

Comment: @MattN: Not true. There are 2 methods of parsing XML markup: DOM (read the whole file into a tree data structure) and SAX (stream in the file and handle tags as they are encountered during parsing). Sounds like a SAX-based xml parsing approach with early termination would suit the OP's needs nicely. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828703/difference-about-sax-and-dom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPath is what you want. For all intents and purposes, you can think of xpath as you would sql, only it is for xml documents instead of databases. Here is a simple example using Java (keep in mind xpath is a standard and not specific to java, so you can find many ways of doing this in pretty much any popular language):

```
    // Load document
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse( new FileInputStream( "/tmp/xml" ) );

    // Create XPath expression
    XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile( "//server01" );

    // Find node 'server01'
    Node node = (Node) expr.evaluate( doc, XPathConstants.NODE );
    if( node == null ) {
        System.out.println( "Node not found" );
        System.exit( 0 );
    }

    // Extract departments
    Element server01 = (Element) node;
    for( int k = 0 ; k < server01.getChildNodes().getLength() ; k++ ) {
        Node childNode = server01.getChildNodes().item( k );
        // Check if current node is a department node
        if( "department".equals( childNode.getNodeName() ) ) {
            System.out.println( childNode.getNodeName() + ": " + childNode.getTextContent().trim() );
        }
    }
```

> Is there is a possibility to avoid this?

Yes just change XPath expression an receive only nodes you need.

```
// Load document
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse( new FileInputStream( "/tmp/xml" ) );

// Create XPath expression
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile( "//server01/department" );

// Find nodes 'department' under node 'server01'
NodeList node = (NodeList) expr.evaluate( doc, XPathConstants.NODESET );

// Extract departments
for( int k = 0 ; k < node.getLength() ; k++ ) {
    Node childNode = node.item( k );
    // Check if current node is a department node
    if( "department".equals( childNode.getNodeName() ) ) {
        System.out.println( "[" + k + "] " + childNode.getNodeName() + ": " + childNode.getTextContent().trim() );
    }
}
```

You must receive the next output:

```
[0] department: A1
[1] department: A2
```

Comment: To ensure I'm not taking points from you as a result of my edits, I've deleted my answer and gave you an upvote since we basically had the same answer.

Comment: Hi. This is a first simple solution. I am not surprised that I was not alone :)

Comment: Thanks! It is very helpful :). But, there is one thing, that is don;t understand. The output from program is:
`null
1 - AP
null
3 - AR
null
5 - GL
null
7 - CS
null
9 - CL
`
Why it count in that way? Not 1,2,3... but only the odd numbers?

Comment: Did you change original example? I've tested it and output shows correct lines:

`department: A1`

Comment: You receive 'department' node on odd iterations because there are '#text' node with '\n' content between tags.

Comment: Is there is a possibility to avoid this?

Comment: Please look second variant in this answer.

Comment: Awesome :) Great thing! I am not able to give you a reputation point. Many thanks for this!