# Child Element SAX parser java

Tags: java, saxparser

I have one node in xml file

```
<abc>
</abc>
```

if i try to get element abc's child 
I m geeting `</abc>` as result but it must be "null"
I m using Saxparser in java

Comment: There is no child..So I have to get answer as "null" but I m getting "</abc>"

Comment: How do you use SAX ? Did you define a SAX Handler ?

Answer (score 1):

DOM Parser loads the whole XML file in its loader.
Hence DOM Parser will allow you to check the childnodes of a given node from your given xml.

SAX Parser reads the xml line by line so checking the child node for a given node wont be possible.

For ur reference:
[What is the difference between SAX and DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828703/what-is-the-difference-between-sax-and-dom)