# how to get specific node and its childs using node's name and a specific attribute value?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

**note :** i am dealing with xml files that i don't know their structure in advance so i can't use XPath
here is an example of my xml files :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>
<HWData>
<Header time="2013-05-29T13:39:34" uploaded="true" version="1.0" />
  <NE vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" NEId="WBTS-431">
    <EQHO vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" equipmentHolderId="173" >
        <UNIT vendorName="N" unitId="16" />
        <UNIT vendorName="NOKIA SIEMENS NETWORKS" unitId="225" />
    </EQHO>
    <EQHO vendorName="NSN" equipmentHolderId="40192" >
        <UNIT vendorName="AR" unitId="40267" />
    </EQHO>
  </NE>
  <NE vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" NEId="WBTS-261">
    <EQHO vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" equipmentHolderId="132" >
      <EQHO vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" equipmentHolderId="132-1">
        <UNIT vendorName="NN" unitId="1621" />
      </EQHO>
    </EQHO>
  </NE>
</HWData>
```

i want to know if i can use for example node name "NE" and attribute value NEID="WBTS-261" to have the hole as result!

result expected :

```
<NE vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" NEId="WBTS-261">
    <EQHO vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" equipmentHolderId="132" >
      <EQHO vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" equipmentHolderId="132-1">
        <UNIT vendorName="NN" unitId="1621" />
      </EQHO>
    </EQHO>
</NE>
```

can someone put me on the right way to do that any example,idea or suggestion will be appreciated.. thank you

Comment: There are several possibilities and there are various tools to do this. Maybe first have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828703/what-is-the-difference-between-sax-and-dom and then use a search engine to find what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this method to the node as string :

```
 public static String NodeToString(String file,String moid) throws   SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException{
String stringNode="";
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(in);
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    if(nodeList.item(i) instanceof Element && ((Element)nodeList.item(i)).getAttribute("MOID").equalsIgnoreCase(moid)){

try
{

  // Set up the output transformer
  TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
  trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
  trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

  // Print the DOM node

  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
  StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
  DOMSource source = new DOMSource(nodeList.item(i));
  trans.transform(source, result);
  stringNode = sw.toString();

  //System.out.println(xmlString);
}
catch (TransformerException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}       


    }
}
return stringNode;

 }
```